# Reverse the direction of line chart

Tags: c#, charts

I have tried many things such as setting `Right to Left` or messing with the `IsReversed` property for `ChartArea` but no go. Any advice?

Sorry for the lack of info, I figured it would be just a switch somewhere in the Chart properties that I was overlooking. Anyways, I am making a custom chart and right now the lines are going from left to right BUT I need it to go in the reverse direction

[image: need to draw the fricking thing from right to left]

I guess another way to put it woudl be how do I add points going from right to left?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at the very least, how you're creating your chart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the direction of X-axis label in ms charts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739303/how-to-change-the-direction-of-x-axis-label-in-ms-charts), or possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736973/c-sharp-winform-mschart-reverse-y-axis

Comment: This is __not a duplicate__ of the linked posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reverse the x-axis all you need to do is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    CA.AxisX.IsReversed = true;
}
```

Before and after:

[image][image]

If you want to keep the y-axis to the left use this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    CA.AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
    CA.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
    CA.AxisX.IsReversed = true;
}
```

[image]

If, as you comment, you simply want to add `DataPoints` to the left, you can do so like this:

```
Series S = chart1.Series[0];
DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(dp.XValue, dp.YValues[0]);
S.Points.Insert(0, dp);
```

This may be a little slower, but it will work just as well as `Adding` them at the end.  You may want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908979/how-to-add-spikes-to-line-on-winform-chart/29914369#29914369), where `DataPoints` are inserted at various spots in the `Points` collection..

Note the `Points` is often accessed like an array but really is of type [DataPointCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so adding and removing and many other operations are readily available.

One common use is removing Points from the left to create a 'moving' chart like an oscillograph..

Comment: woah, this is fancy but not exactly what I was looking for. I am just trying to figure out how to add points starting from the right side of the chart area going left.

Comment: I will try this out a little later today, I'm trying to mimic the Windows task manager performance graph if you needed some context as to what my end goal was. Thanks

Comment: I thought so after seeing the image. Insert at 0 and when you have more than a limit Remove at Points.Count then..!